# Retrieve all project variables via REST call (jbpm)

Tags: jbpm

For our project we are looking to:

- build a workflow in the workbench
- build a rich user interface that accesses and displays information from the workflow

On the user interface we are hoping to include a feature that does this:

- gives the user the ability to view all variables associated with the entire workflow
- the idea being that we want to give them an over-view of the project to give them context while completing their tasks.

We've toyed around a bit and so far have been unsuccessful in pulling the data back that we'd like.

- So is this possible?
- If so, what are some solutions?
- Which endpoints will work for us?
- Is extending an endpoint a potential solution? If so, how do we do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far we've tried:

- experimenting with the native remote api
- persisting process data into our own database using persistence strategies

Initially we were unsuccessful with both, but eventually we decided on an implementation that passed a process id throughout our entire workflow, and creating a one to one mapping between each task model and the process id. In other words, for each jbpm workflow task we built our own form on the front end, and persisted data to our own database. The only thing that that tied the entire project together and allowed us to query for all of the data, was the process id that we initialized in the beginning.

This meant that jbpm ended up handling little to nothing about our app, other than the movement between tasks, and tying it all together via project id.

Comment: It is a basic key/value structure feature. But if you combine the Variables with business rules, you can empower your business process a lot.

Comment: Actually I wouldn't recommend mixing application data with process data. It's a good practice to have your app db outside the jBPM structure and reference it using the process instance id or the task id.

Comment: After a few weeks we've managed to get the intended affect by removing as much logic away from jbpm as possible and into our front-end and custom database. We're passing an id through the workflow and associating it with our own persistence data, using our own service to retrieve a project view. JBPM is doing nothing but keeping track of workflow.

Comment: Consider to mark the answer as correct to close the question. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of these two options to retrieve the Process Variables in the REST api:

```
/rest/runtime/{deploymentId}/withvars/process/instance/{procInstanceId}
```

returns the Process Instance with all its Variables, and:

```
/rest/history/instance/{procInstanceId}/variable
```

returns a list of variable history records for a process instance.

You can have the documentation here: [jBPM Remote API](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.1/userguide/jBPMRemoteAPI.html)

Comment: We've looked into the remote api and found it not fully fleshed out enough for our purposes, too many limitations in the calls.